# Deserializing a space delimited string into a Generic List

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have an xml file with elements that look like this (abbreviated for clarity):

```
<post id="1" tags="tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4" />
```

I want to map this to the following class using Xml Deserialization, but I can't find a way to map the tags attribute to an actual List(Of String).

```
<Serializable()> _
<XmlRootAttribute("post")> _
Public Class Post
Private m_id As Integer
Private m_tags As String

<XmlAttribute("id")> _
Public Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_id = value
    End Set
End Property

'<XmlAttribute("tags")> _
Public Property Tags() As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return m_tags
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
        m_tags = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Is there any way to override the default Deserialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is to have a `RawTags` get/set property which gets serialized, and a `Tags` readonly property which parses the RawTags to a `List<string>` but gets ignored by the serializer:

```
<Serializable()> 
    <XmlRootAttribute("post")> 
    Public Class Post
    Private m_id As Integer
    Private m_tags As String

    <XmlAttribute("id")> 
    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_id = value
        End Set
    End Property

   <XmlAttribute("tags")> 
    Public Property RawTags() As String
        Get
            Return m_tags 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_tags = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlIgnore>
    Public ReadOnly Property Tags() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_tags.Split(" ").ToList()
        End Get
    End Property
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but the deserializer will just see that as a string, the same as "tag1tag2tag3tag4". I don't know that you can deserialize into a list via delimiters.

You can serialize the attribute to a variable and then create the Tags() property via a string split into an array and then array.ToList(). I'm not sure if there's a slick deserialization way to go about it, but that will certainly work.