# XmlElement has a list as attribute but its items aren't separated by comma

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

What I want to get:

```
<Body numbers="20.55,30.40,25.55,35.40,40.55,45.40">
```

What I get:

```
<Body numbers="20.55 30.40 25.55 35.40 40.55 45.40">
```

Here is how I add them in code:

```
//a for loop for every Body
    newBody.numbers.Add(myQuery[j].x);
    newBody.numbers.Add(myQuery[j].y);
```

Comment: What is `newBody.numbers`? And why wouldn't you serialize each number as a child element?

Comment: This might help you out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823793/deserializing-a-space-delimited-string-into-a-generic-list

Comment: How exactly do you convert `newBody` into XML? I think this question can't be properly answered without knowing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a calculated property of type string which will format the numbers as you desire:

```
private float[] _numbers;
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "numbers")]
public string Numbers
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(",", _numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work only with XML serialization. It's not clear to me from the question that's what OP uses.

Comment: @svick, given that he tagged his question with `xml serialization` it's a good hint that he is using XmlSerializer. If he isn't, well, he should have shown his code and stated what exactly he has tried so far.

Comment: ah, sorry, I overlooked that.

Comment: @svick, no, I think that your remark makes sense. In questions where OPs do not show their code and do not provide any context it is perfectly normal that their questions do not make sense and people have different interpretations.